# Giving pagination for custom module in OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, pagination, openerp-7

By default, OpenERP displays 20 records when retrieving data. Is there any way I can change the default number of records to something else to number? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The default limit for a list view is set on the corresponding Window Action.

This can be changed by going to

Settings -> Customization -> Low Level Objects -> Actions -> Window Actions

and then open the Action from there.

When you do, you will see the default value in the Limit field - and you can change this value from 80 to anything you want:

[image]

I hope this helps you.

Thanks And Regards

Yaseen Shareef

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, is that option is available in OpenERP 7?

Comment: I edited in ir.action and made the changes, but it is not affecting in tabs it is only affecting for menus, for example it is affecting only on created number of modules, it is not affecting inside the modules like i have created tabs in said that modules i need to do pagination for that. is there any solutions of that